# A question about inverse Green's function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, greens-functions

(The background is in a book, An introduction to String Theory and D-brane Dynamics 2nd, by Richard J Szabo p87, Eq. (6.31))

Given 
$$N(\theta,\theta')= - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos ( n (\theta-\theta') )}{n} \tag{1} $$,

it is said the inverse is 
$$ N^{-1}(\theta,\theta') = - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cos ( n (\theta - \theta') )   \tag{1} $$

Attempt for solving the problem:
I hope I can get 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} d \theta' N(\theta,\theta') N^{-1}(\theta',\theta'') = \delta(\theta-\theta'')  \tag{3} $$

I tried to write Eqs. (1) and (2) as
$$ N = - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos ( n \theta ) \cos (n \theta')  + \sin ( n \theta ) \sin (n \theta') }{n}$$

$$ N^{-1} = - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m \left(  \cos ( m \theta' ) \cos (m \theta'')  + \sin ( m \theta' ) \sin (m \theta'')  \right) $$

Multiply $N$ and $N^{-1}$ and integrating over $\theta'$, by the product-to-sum formula of trigonometric function, only $\cos \cos$ and $\sin \sin$ crossing terms survive. Notice from both $\cos \cos$ and $\sin \sin$ only $\cos (n-m) \theta'$ if $n=m$ survives, and use the angle sum identity, skip this smoke, hopefully I am correct, (if necessary, I can supply the intermediate steps) the result is
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(n (\theta-\theta'') ) $$

But the completeness relation of the Fourier series is
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos \left( n (\theta-\theta'') \right) = \delta  (\theta - \theta'') - \frac{1}{2\pi} $$, where did I miss $ - \frac{1}{2\pi} $ ?

Comment: I wonder if it is not OK. In this [reference](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6059v2.pdf), we see in formulae ($17$) page $4$ and ($28$) page $6$ that Dirichlet and Neumann Green functions do not obey to the same equation ($G_N$ would be the equivalent of $N$ and ${\mathcal{L}}_{x'}$ would be the equivalent of $N^{-1}$).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked the reference where Richard J Szabo mentioned, Fradkin and Tseytlin, Phys. Lett. 163B, 123 (1985). In Eq. (16) there is a statement, $\ddot{G} \cdot G = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \cos m \zeta \equiv \bar{\delta}(\theta-\theta')$, where $\bar{\delta}$ is a function defined on non-constant functions. ($\ddot{G} = G^{-1}$). It seems $-\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is by definition excluded.

Comment: OK, I supposed you mean something like $\int_{-\pi}^{+ \pi} d\theta  ~\bar \delta(\theta ) = 0$

Comment: Yes. That is more or less I thought about.